# window.google is undefined in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

When I call window and console log it I get a google prop as you see here:

[image]

Yet when I try to call `window.google` I get undefined. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you making sure you are doing that call *after* you reference the Google API library and not before?

Comment: try `this.google`

Answer (score 6):

Hey I came across a similar issue trying to instantiate a **new window.google.maps.Map** and found this solution helped me.

1. When declaring your `<script>` tag, give it an identifier so that you can grab it later in your component.
2. On the mounting of your component, set up a `load` event listener on the Google script and wait until it's ready before executing any more code.
3. One caveat is that if your script is loaded before this component mounts (what we'd hope for in the first place) and sets up the event listener, nothing will happen. We want to catch this positive condition with `if (window.google)`

```
componentDidMount() {
  const googleScript = document.getElementById('google-map-script')

  if (window.google) {
    // All is good! Carry on 
  }

  googleScript.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // Patiently waiting to do the thing 
  })
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, that is i stopped getting `undefined` error, but sometimes I have to refresh the page in order for my api to work (in production).

Answer (score 2):

Since that looks like the Google Maps API, its probably a load order issue.

Make sure that the `<script>` that is pulling in the Google Maps tag comes before the one that runs your React code.

If that isn't the problem, you may need to wrap your React code in some kind of `ready()` function to force it to wait until the Google code is ready.