# Google translate snippet not working in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, translation

I'm trying to add a Google Translate solution to my app (the objective is to automatically translate the client-custom content of the app when it loads, based on the device preferred language).

I stumbled upon this snippet, but my IDE flags the `window.googleTranslateElementInit` and the `window.google` elements as not found.

This comes from this snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bblv1z?file=index.tsx

Is this script event supported?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let addScript = document.createElement('script');
  addScript.setAttribute(
      'src',
      'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'
  );
  document.body.appendChild(addScript);
  window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit;
}, []);

  const googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
     new window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {
          pageLanguage: 'ta',
          includedLanguages: 'en,ms,ta,zh-CN,fr', // include this for selected languages
             layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
        },
        'google_translate_element'
     );
  };

// ...

// component return
//...
   <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Comment: a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030311/window-google-is-undefined-in-react